# iPhone webapp: How let user to view a file and survive

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I've got a webapp,  that runs in full screen mode.
Part of it is, that the user can download a file and view it on iPhone.

The problem is, when I let download the file and user sees it in a viewer app, my app gets status of a background application and iOS kills it. So, when the user leaves the viewer, my app is gone. What wasn't really intended.

Is there a way for my app to survive the file download & view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Awesome title. Didn't know viewing files on iPhone kills people!

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? add some code? Sounds like you return or exit or quit at a wrong place? Or is that you access a freed object and get a bus error? Impossible to tell from your description

Comment: Webapp got killed. About people  I'm not sure. My page has a button, that onclick does window.location=path_to_file.pdf. After a click user sees the file, webapp goes to background and get closed by iOS.

Comment: Probably is the issue described here http://goo.gl/omztO , but may be someone has good advice to deal with it.

Comment: only way is to do cordova/phonegap, that's it